# How can I get a random file in linux? including subdirectories

Tags: c, linux, bash

Lets say I am in /home/myuser

there are 90,000 files there inside 3000 directories.

How can I write a bash function or with linux commands to get one random file?

It could be C as well I suppose

Comment: Does each file have to have equal probability of being chosen? Is the directory tree deep, with subdirectories within subdirectories? Do you have performance requirements? Do you need to choose among only a certain type of file, such as files with the extension ".mp3"?

Comment: Show code of what you have tried already.

Comment: need .phtml, .php, xml  file sonlyu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list all your files and then pick a random line between them:

```
find /home/myuser | sort -R | head -n1
```

However this is not very efficient, and could take a while, but is easy to understand. You can work from here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shuf` for this task, for example set `globstar` option and try

```
shuf -e path/**/*.txt | head -n1
```